# socketIO over SSL on Smartphone Browser

Tags: ssl, browser, websocket, socket.io, smartphone

I have an Apache webserver with a valid SSL certificate. It runs my web application on it. Let's call it Server A.

Then I have a second server running a Node-Js server with a valid SSL certificate. There also socket.IO runs. And this one we call Server B.

A client requests the web application at server A and gets the desired page displayed. If the page is set up at the client, a connection to server B is established via websockets. If another client should change something on the page, it will be adapted for all currently connected clients.

Websockets work as desired. As long as the page is accessed via a computer browser.

If I now go to the website with my smartphone (Iphone 7) via Safari or Chrome (WLAN), no connection to the websocket server (Server B) is established.

Then I set up a small websocket example on http without encryption.
There the websockets work on the smartphone browser.

I hope I could describe my problem understandably. I am very grateful for hints, examples or similar.

```js
// This script run on my Server
const fs = require('fs');
const server = require('https').createServer({
  key: fs.readFileSync('myserver.key', 'utf8'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('myserver.cer', 'utf8'),
  passphrase: ''
});
let io = require('socket.io')(server);
server.listen(3003);

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  console.log("User Connected connect " + socket.id);

  socket.on('disconnect', function () {
    console.log("User has close the browser " + socket.id);
  });

  socket.on('feedback', function (data) {
    io.sockets.emit('feedback', data);
  });
});

// On Clientsite
  socket = io.connect('wss://adressOfServer:3003', {
    // secure: true,
    transports: ['websocket'],
    upgrade: false,
    rejectUnauthorized: false
    //Here I have already tried many combinations 
  });
  
  socket.on('connect_error', function (error) {
  // alert(error);
});
```

Comment: Please add some relevant code, like how you initialize socket.io on client/server...

Comment: @TamasSzoke i edit my post. Thanks for your time. As said on a computer no matter which browser everything works fine. Only smartphones can't connect.